# finding control in grid view?

Tags: asp.net

in my application i am trying to get the checkbox which is in the gridview i use the foreach control but it is shoing null this is my code./..

source

'>
                     ' Visible ="false" >
                  
                
                
                  
                     '>
                  
                  
                     ' TextMode="multiLine"  >
                  
                
                
                  
                     '>
                  
                  
                     ' TextMode="multiLine"  >
                  
                
                
                  
                   '>
                  
                  
                      ' />

public void getPlaylist()//i write the finding control in a method 
    {
        MyplalistBL clsMyplalstBl=new MyplalistBL ();
        clsMyplalstBl.Userid = Session["userid"].ToString();
        DataSet ds = clsMyplalstBl.getPlaylistBl();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {

```
        grdplaylist .DataSource =ds.Tables [0];
        grdplaylist.DataBind();

        foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdplaylist.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chksett");
            string s = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["settings"].ToString();

            if (s == "P")
            {
                ch.Checked = true;
            }
            else if (s == "PV")
            {
                ch.Checked = false;
            }


        }


    }
    else
    {
        grdplaylist.DataSource = null;
        grdplaylist.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Comment: I will explain clearly in my gridview a check box is there. the check box should checked when it is "P" and un checked when it is "PV" this comes from database. how can i. how can i declare the check box in grid i declare like this
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chksett" runat ="Server" Text ='<%# Eval("settings") %>' />
is it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is interesting...
It looks that you want to load your check box status from database, 
so, what you should do is, shift your code to grid view's databound event and it would start working

Comment: you would need to check for rowType in databound event otherwise it may throw up an exception if u try to find a checkbox in the header or footer(if the gridview has one)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the checkbox based on value in table you can use the Row_DataBound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow & (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal | e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBoc1");
        string s= ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row("settings");
        if (s== "P") {
            cb.Checked = true;
        }
        else if (s== "PV") {
            cb.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct you should have something like:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    string dropDownListText = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

For markup:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField = "Name" DataSource= '<%# BindDropDownList() %>' runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
```

So I would try to make sure your naming is correct.  Make sure you have it named "chksett" indeed.

If that doesn't work move it to an RowBound or ItemBound event.

Comment: Here's a decent sample with a checkbox that is probably similar to your situation: http://highoncoding.com/Articles/81_Selecting_Checkboxes_inside_GridView_Control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this :

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdplaylist.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)gr[gr.RowIndex].FindControl("chksett");
            string s = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["settings"].ToString();

            if (s == "P")
            {
                ch.Checked = true;
            }
            else if (s == "PV")
            {
                ch.Checked = false;
            }
        }
```